# How can I link and sort multiple variables?

Tags: python

I am reading a text file that has a filename and a mean statistic in the form of a number, such as:

FILENAME

0.6597

This is repeated over and over as this is a report generated from a program. I am wondering how I can make it so I can combine the filename and statistic so they will never be separated from each other. Then be able to sort them by file name and statistic at the same time. The filenames will have substrings within it that can be matched to other filenames with the same substring. This substring denotes their physical location on the earth and must be grouped accordingly. Once they are sorted based on how the substrings in the filenames match, I could then sort them by which of those has the highest mean (the number). Here is what I have so far.

```
def openfile():
list = []

with open('TestReportWrite.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Processed' in line:
            list.append(line)
        elif '.' in line:
            list.append(line)
        else:
            pass
return list
```

I can successfully build a list but the filename and statistics are not linked to each other and wont be sorted together. I am not too sure how to link them.

An example of the filename is LC08_L1TP_027042_20190917_20190925_01_T1
The part I would be want to sort by is the *027042* the rest does not matter.

The exact format of the file I am reading is the file path immediately followed by a stat (in the form of a number) on a new line. Here is a made up example
[image]

Comment: Can you give us more details on the file format? What is this "Processed" thing? Does it always alternate FILENAME, some blank lines, the stat, some blank lines?

Comment: Maybe, just give a few lines from the file you are reading. If it's sensitive, just mask whatever you do not want to share with some kind of placeholder.

Comment: I think you're after the Python `dict` datatype, which will allow you to associate the 'mean' value with each filename, as long as your filenames are unique (which it appears they would be, based on your description). Your code doesn't entirely match your description though - what's the significance of `'Processed'`?

Comment: You can use `list` of `tuples`. for example, `[("name1", 0.1), ("name2", 0.3)]`. You can pass "what is the sorting key" parameter to sort function. `list_.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`. And if you need random access, you can use `OrderedDict` or just `dict`(be careful about dealing with simple `dict` type since it is not guaranteed its ordering).

Comment: @tdelaney I added some more information to clarify.

Comment: @jsfan I added a screenshot of what the text file would look like.

Comment: Please quote text as text, not Screenshots

Comment: @dillonforsythe Your code refers to the string "Processed" but I do not see that word in your screenshot at all. Why are you looking for that string in your loop?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like filename/stats alternate every other line. You can read filename, split on the underscores to pull out potentially interesting information then add the next line as the stats value. Now you can sort on any column you want.

```
def openfile():
    my_list = []
    with open('TestReportWrite.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # assuming the underscores split the interesting parts
            # consistently
            columns = line.strip().split('_')
            # add the stats
            columns.append(next(f).strip())
            my_list.append(parts)
    # sorted by the part you want in column 2
    my_list.sort(key=lambda col:col[2])
    return my_list
```

Comment: You can also do it in just one loop if you hold the filename in a variable until you get to the value and then clear it until you find another one.

Comment: It's not working. Because outer `for` statement runs only once in your code.

Comment: @Rubato - yeah, I forgot to break the second loop. But OP's example data is quite different than the original description, so I changed to a single loop with a next().